# Add media queries rules for not supported browser/devices

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm just doing a research about `media queries`.

I wrote an email based on `media queries` and some devices support them, but some other, the style looks horrible.

I found this page:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/media-queries/media/

There explains a lot about the compatibility of each one of the tags.

But, here is my question:

For example, `Outlook for windows` doesn't support media queries but, for `Mac` it supported.

How can I define `CSS` default rules for not supported `media queries browser` and apps?

Comment: Almost every single modern browser (including IE 9) [**fully supports**](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries) basic media queries (with over 97% global coverage). Email clients are completely different, and many mobile email clients do not support them. Gmail is notoriously bad for messing up email styles. For emails you should use tables instead.

Comment: Yes, I know @ObsidianAge, but is part of the requirements, and I need be sure about if is possible or not before to take a decision.

Comment: So what's your actual question? How to style emails in lieu of the fact that media queries won't work? Use tables with percentage values, following the [**hybrid email design**](https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-responsive-and-hybrid-email-design). If you are literally asking how you can add media queries to devices which don't support media queries, the answer is that you can't.